# Maven not outputting junit CHECKSTYLE report

Tags: maven, junit, checkstyle

After default config, maven is only outputting the [**Checkstyle report**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html) for source classes, not Junit test classes.  Note I'm not looking for the surefire test report output.

from pom.xml:

```
<reporting>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
          <reports>
            <report>checkstyle</report>
          </reports>
        </reportSet>
      </reportSets>
      <configuration>
        <configLocation>src/main/resources/apcheckstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <module name="LineLength">
          <property name="max" value="120"/>
        </module>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I changed dependency scope for junit from **test** to **compile**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maven is configured to generate the checkstyle reports using the mvn site plugin.
I tried adding a user property [includeTestResources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html) as true, but this did not help. The documentation states that the default value is true, so I took it out.

Here is the maven output during checkstyle generation.

from javadocs:

> Generating C:\Users\Administrator\Projects\lht657aws\target\site\testapidocs\help-doc.html...

checkstyle plugin runs:

> [INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17
>
> [INFO] There are 210 errors reported by Checkstyle 6.11.2 with src/main/resources/apcheckstyle.xml ruleset.

is following the problem-?  all the java under src is getting processed, just java under test is being skipped:

> [WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED

after checkstyle, maven project info report starts

> [INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.9

Comment: Edited to clarify that this is actually about the checkstyle report and added the output from Maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the Maven Surefire Report plugin to your pom XML

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>path/to/the/report</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And add the goal `surefire-report:report` to your maven call

See the documentation here: [Maven Surefire Report Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)

**EDIT**

I've misunderstood the question, try to add this section with desired configurations to your pom.

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
      <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
          <id>main_checks</id>
          <reports>
            <report>checkstyle</report>
          </reports>
          <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
            <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            <configLocation>config/maven_checks.xml</configLocation>
            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/main-checks/</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </reportSet>
        <reportSet>
          <id>test_checks</id>
          <reports>
            <report>checkstyle</report>
          </reports>
          <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory></sourceDirectory>
            <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
            <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/test-checks/</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </reportSet>
      </reportSets>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge i see this is a common issue everywhere as it's made it hard for me to find the answer to *my* question. I am interested in [Checkstyle report,](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html) not a test report..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See my edit and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it.  This got me totally on the right track. The problem was that I had the `configuration` node at the `plugin` level and not at the `reportSet` level.   Note that I could not get 2.6 to work with my custom configuration file, it appears there is a [bug](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/599) resurfacing.  So I am at 2.17.  Please update your answer or I can put in an answer.

Comment: Ok! Edited. Glad that you could solve your problem. I left this old version because it was from an old answer mine. Forgot to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Maven sure fire plugin is used for generating the Test reports. See the additional documentation here:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/

You need to include this plugin in your POM.xml and provide path to create reports (generally a directory in project). While making the build make sure you are including goal for this.

Comment: I am interested in [Checkstyle report,](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html)  not Test reports.  Checkstyle reports assess the syntax of the java in the test classes.

Comment: Ohh!! My bad..solution proposed by John above is totally correct my :+1 for that.